# Android, RelativeLayout.BELOW not working inside ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

Imagine this hierarchy:
Case 1

```
RelativeLayout (screen size)
        |
        -> RelativeLayout (centered)
        |   |->TextView
        |
        |
        -> buttonLayout (below the former RelativeLayout)
            |->Button
```

With this I get the expected result, a textview in the middle of the screen and just below a button.

But if I add a scroll:

```
Case 2
    ScrollView
    |
    -> RelativeLayout (screen size)
        |
        -> RelativeLayout (centered)
        |   |->TextView
        |
        |
        -> buttonLayout (below the former RelativeLayout)
            |->Button
```

Then the everything looks the same but the button ignores the 'below rule' and is displayed almost at the top of the screen. I just can not understand why. Any help?

Thanks for helping.
Greg

The code:
//Ready for case 2

```
 public View createOwnLayout()
   {    
        ScrollView scrollView =  new ScrollView(this);//Comment for case 1
        RelativeLayout parentView = new RelativeLayout(this);
        parentView.setBackgroundColor(0xff990000);

            //--------------------------------- LINEAR LLAYOUT ---------------------------------//
            LinearLayout centerLL = new LinearLayout(this);
            centerLL.setId(CommonOpsAndValues.CONNECTION_ACTIVITY_IMAGE_LINEAR_LAYOUT);
            centerLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            centerLL.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rainbow);
            centerLL.setBackgroundColor(0xff555599);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams centerLLLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            centerLLLP.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            centerLLLP.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);   
            parentView.addView(centerLL,centerLLLP);
            TextView serverLabel = new TextView(this);
            serverLabel.setText("HELLO");
            serverLabel.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
            serverLabel.setTextSize(LABEL_TEXT_SIZE);
            serverLabel.setPadding(INPUT_TEXTBOX_TEXT_PADDING, 0,0,0);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams serverLabelLLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            serverLabelLLP.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            centerLL.addView(serverLabel,serverLabelLLP);
            //---------------------------- LINEAR LLAYOUT ---------------------------/
            //---------------------------- BUTTON LAYOUT---------------------------/
            LinearLayout buttonLayout = new LinearLayout(this); 
                buttonLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            buttonLayout.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
            Button button = new Button(this);       
            button.setText("DO");
            button.setClickable(true);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            buttonLayout.addView(button,buttonLP );
            //---------------------------- BUTTON LAYOUT ---------------------------/


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonLayoutLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,                                                                             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        buttonLayoutLP.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        buttonLayoutLP.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,centerLL.getId());
        parentView.addView(buttonLayout,buttonLayoutLP);        
        scrollView.addView(parentView,new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(AppManager.g_ScreenWidth,AppManager.g_ScreenHeight));//Comment for case 1
        scrollView.setFillViewport(false);//Comment for case 1  

        //return parentView; //Uncomment for case 1
        return scrollView;//Comment for case 1

 }
```

Comment: I tend to be obnoxious when I'm preaching about XML layouts, so bear with me. Is there any reason for this to not be an XML layout? It becomes a million times easier to debug layout issues for numerous reasons. The biggest reason is that yo can edit the layout in real time. I know I won't even bother reading through that code, because programmatic layouts are a pain in the ass.

Comment: @Mike Agreed.  Why make your layout in 100 lines of Java code?  Very unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the following just after you create scrollView:

```
scrollView.setFillViewport( true );
```

I would agree with Mike's comment that using an XML layout would make it much easier to maintain, and you have the advantage of a visual editor in the current version of ADT.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please mark this as the "accepted answer" as detailed at http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask. That way others will know that the fix works.

Comment: Thanks Mark it worked. I tried to do it with XML but I changed my mind. My experience has been better making GUIs with code than with XML or visual editors, more work but less problems for complex interfaces.

Comment: Ups, I changed the TextView for an EditText. When I touch it and the keyboard is shown, I want to be able to scroll to the EditText or to the button.
Surprisingly when the keyboard appears, the button changes its layout and is drawn in the middle of the screen, the EditText does not move although
it is partially hidden by the keyboard (that is what I wanted). I don't understand why the button changes its layout, any idea of how can I avoid this?

Thanks.
Greg.

Comment: @Mark why would that work?  I tried it in my XML layout, and it made no difference whatsoever.